# How to Bounce or Zoom Animation on press on button

Tags: java, android, android-animation

I want to animation like that on the press.

[image]

I am use this

```
 <scale
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:duration="200"
android:fillAfter="true" 
android:fromXScale="0.9"
android:fromYScale="0.9"
android:pivotX="50%"
android:pivotY="50%"
android:toXScale="1.0"
android:toYScale="1.0" >
```

```
 mBounceAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(LoginActivity.this,R.anim.bounce);



       btnLogin.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    btnLogin.startAnimation(mBounceAnimation);
                    // start your first zoom out Animation here
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
               // start zoom in animation which returns to original  state
                    btnLogin.clearAnimation();
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: You can use this library for animation purpose. it is easy and contains lots of animations. [AndroidViewAnimations](https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidViewAnimations)

Comment: Thankyou @Nilesh